# Is there any way to access the elements in the sprite group?

Tags: python, pygame

I completed my first project but I wanted to more features. I'm doing this project from a book called 'Python Crash Course'. I want the aliens to shoot the bullets which will hit the alien. But I can't seem to find a way to shoot the bullets from aliens.

I have tried passing firing bullet in function in create alien function but nothing worked :(

```
'''This is the fucntions used to create a fleet of aliens.'''

def get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien_width):
    """Determine the number of aliens that fit in a row."""
    available_space_x = ai_settings.screen_width - 2 * alien_width
    number_aliens_x = int(available_space_x / (2 * alien_width))
    return number_aliens_x


def get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship_height, alien_height):
    """Determine the number of aliens that fit on screen."""
    available_space_y = (ai_settings.screen_height - (3 * alien_height) - ship_height)
    number_rows = int(available_space_y / (2 * alien_height))
    return number_rows


def create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number, row_number):
    """Create an alien and place it in a row."""
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    alien_width = alien.rect.width
    alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
    alien.rect.x = alien.x
    alien.rect.y = alien.rect.height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number
    aliens.add(alien)


def create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens):
    """Create a full fleet of aliens."""
    # Create an alien and find the number of aliens in a row
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    number_aliens_x = get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien.rect.width)
    number_rows = get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship.rect.height, alien.rect.height)

    # Create the first row of aliens
    for row_number in range(number_rows):
        for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
            create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number, row_number)
```

I expect the aliens to shoot bullets towards ship.

Comment: At some point the alien needs to decide to create a "bullet", that can happen in the sprite `update()` function.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose `aliens` is the `sprite.Group()`.

In that case, you can iterate over all the sprites in the group by using the [sprite.Group.sprites](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.sprites) method.

```
for al in aliens.sprites():
    #use al to make the single sprite shooting
```